# How does EnumClass.values() work in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

How does `EnumClass.values()` work in Kotlin?

I mean will it create new `Array` every time, or it is lazy evaluated static, or something else?

Comment: not exactly a duplicate (as it deals with Kotlin here). But printing the byte code using `javap` we know that `java.lang.Enum` is used under the hood. So the same applies to Kotlin as well.

Answer (score 2):

While not 100% sure, I assume that in **Kotlin** (as well as in **Java**) `Enum.values()` method is generated by the compiler:

> The compiler automatically adds some special methods when it creates
>   an enum. For example, they have a static values method that returns an
>   array containing all of the values of the enum in the order they are
>   declared. This method is commonly used in combination with the
>   for-each construct to iterate over the values of an enum type.

From the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.2):

```
/**
* Returns an array containing the constants of this enum 
* type, in the order they're declared.  This method may be
* used to iterate over the constants as follows:
*
*    for(E c : E.values())
*        System.out.println(c);
*
* @return an array containing the constants of this enum 
* type, in the order they're declared
*/
public static E[] values();
```

---

This method ***returns new array*** every time.

The point is that an array can't be constant in **Java**: it values can be modified, so you can't share the same array and have to give a new one on every access to guarantee that the array hasn't been changed.

**Simple test:**

```
enum class MyEnum { CAT, DOG }

val a = MyEnum.values()
val b = MyEnum.values()

println("${a === b}") // >>> false

a[0] = MyEnum.DOG
println(a.joinToString())               // >>> [DOG, DOG]
println(MyEnum.values().joinToString()) // >>> [CAT, DOG]
```

Comment: Actually I also think it's using the same enum mechanism as Java here and then the array will be cloned, when returned.